# Copy paste values of specific cells in same Google sheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, sourceforge-appscript

I have a Google sheet I want to move only values of specific cells to specific cells from one tab to another at required destination only when I will click a move button present in the tab
How will it be done

I know only basics of copy paste but not in detail

Comment: Do you want to learn how to do it or you just want someone to do it for you? in the first case, people here expect that you show them what you have tried, what you want to achieve exactly and where you are struggling to achieve your goal. In the second case, most people will not be willing to even look at your question

Comment: function copypaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var source = copySheet.getRange(5,2,5,13);
  var source1 = source.getValues();
  var paste1 = pasteSheeet.setRange(5,2,5,13);
  source1.setValues(paste1);
  source1.clearContent();
}           it is not running here is some problem

Comment: Please don't add code in comments; it's too hard to read. [Edit] your question instead. What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wish to move them to the same cell locations on another sheet:

Select the cells on the source sheet before running the function.

```
function moveSelectCells() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rgl = sh.getActiveRangeList(); 
  const brgl = breakUpRangeList(ss,sh,rgl);
  brgl.getRanges().forEach((rg,i)=> {
    let rgA1 = rg.getA1Notation();
    dsh.getRange(rg.getA1Notation()).setValue(rg.getValue())
  });
}
```

Support Function

```
function breakUpRangeList(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0"), rgl) {
  let b = [];
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg => {
    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
      let row = rg.getRow() + i;
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;
        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())
      })
    })
  })
  b = [...new Set(b)];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
  return sh.getRangeList(b);
}
```

Since your question was incomplete I imagine you will have follow up questions.

A different solution:

google apps script:

```
function getSourceRangeList() {
  console.log("source range list")
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const srcrgl = breakUpRangeList(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
  return { src: srcrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation()), srcsht: sh.getName() }
}

function getDestinationRangeList() {
  console.log("destination range list")
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const desrgl = breakUpRangeList(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
  return { des: desrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation()), dessht: sh.getName() }
}

function launchRangeListMoveDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'), "Move Seleccted Values")
}

function makeYourMove(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName(obj.srcsht);
  const sshrgl = ssh.getRangeList(obj.srcrgl.split(','));
  const srgs = sshrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation());
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName(obj.dessht);
  const dshrgl = dsh.getRangeList(obj.desrgl.split(','));
  const drgs = dshrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation());
  srgs.forEach((rg, i) => {
    dsh.getRange(drgs[i]).setValue(ssh.getRange(srgs[i]).getValue());
    ssh.getRange(srgs[i]).clearContent();
  });
}
```

html: ('ah2')

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>input{padding:2px 5px 2px 0px;margin:5px;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="srcrgl" name="srcrgl" /> Source RangeList
      <input type="text" id="srcsht" name="srcsht" /> Source Sheet Name
      <br><input type="button" value="Get Src RGL" onClick="getSrcRgl();" />
      <br><input type="text" id="desrgl" name="desrgl" /> Destination RangeList
      <input type="text" id="dessht" name="dessht" /> Destination Sheet Name
      <br><input type="button" value="Get Dest RGL" onClick="getDestRgl();" />
      <br><input type="button" value="Move" onClick="moveContents(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function getSrcRgl() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((obj) => {document.getElementById("srcrgl").value=obj.src.join(',');document.getElementById("srcsht").value=obj.srcsht;})
        .getSourceRangeList();
      }
      function getDestRgl() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((obj) => {document.getElementById("desrgl").value=obj.des.join(',');document.getElementById("dessht").value=obj.dessht})
        .getDestinationRangeList();
      }
      function moveContents(obj) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(()=>{google.script.host.close()})
        .makeYourMove(obj);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

The thing I really like about functions with dialogs is that you can really tweak them a lot to do things that you want to add laterl

gas:

```
function getSourceRangeList() {
  console.log("source range list")
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const srcrgl = breakUpRangeList(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
  return { src: srcrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation()), srcsht: sh.getName() }
}

function getDestinationRangeList() {
  console.log("destination range list")
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const desrgl = breakUpRangeList(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
  return { des: desrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation()), dessht: sh.getName() }
}

function launchRangeListMoveDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'), "Move Seleccted Values")
}

function testmym() {
  makeYourMove({ "desrgl": "A1,A2,A3,A4", "srcsht": "Sheet0", "dessht": "Sheet1", "srcrgl": "B4,C5,D6,E7" });
}

function makeYourMove(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName(obj.srcsht);
  const sshrgl = ssh.getRangeList(obj.srcrgl.split(','));
  const srgs = sshrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation());
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName(obj.dessht);
  const dshrgl = dsh.getRangeList(obj.desrgl.split(','));
  const drgs = dshrgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getA1Notation());
  srgs.forEach((rg, i) => {
    dsh.getRange(drgs[i]).setValue(ssh.getRange(srgs[i]).getValue());
    if(!obj.toggleCopy) {
      ssh.getRange(srgs[i]).clearContent();
    }
  });
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      input{padding:2px 5px 2px 0px;margin:5px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="srcrgl" name="srcrgl" /> Source RangeList
      <input type="text" id="srcsht" name="srcsht" /> Source Sheet Name
      <br><input type="button" value="Get Src RGL" onClick="getSrcRgl();" />
      <br><input type="text" id="desrgl" name="desrgl" /> Destination RangeList
      <input type="text" id="dessht" name="dessht" /> Destination Sheet Name
      <br><input type="button" value="Get Dest RGL" onClick="getDestRgl();" />
      <br><input type="button" id="movebtn" value="Move" onClick="moveContents(this.parentNode);" /><input id="mdm" type="checkbox" name="toggleCopy" onClick="toggleCheck();"/> Don't delete source values
    </form>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <script>
      function getSrcRgl() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((obj) => {document.getElementById("srcrgl").value=obj.src.join(',');document.getElementById("srcsht").value=obj.srcsht;})
        .getSourceRangeList();
      }
      function getDestRgl() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((obj) => {document.getElementById("desrgl").value=obj.des.join(',');document.getElementById("dessht").value=obj.dessht})
        .getDestinationRangeList();
      }
      function moveContents(obj) {
        let sl = document.getElementById("srcrgl").value.split(",").length;
        let dl = document.getElementById("desrgl").value.split(",").length;
        if(sl != dl) {
          window.alert("Number of Source and Destination elements does not match");
          document.getElementById("srcrgl").focus();
          return;
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(()=>{google.script.host.close()})
        .makeYourMove(obj);
      }
      function toggleCheck() {
        let st = document.getElementById('mdm').checked;
        if(st) {
          document.getElementById("movebtn").value = "Copy";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("movebtn").value = "Move"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]